# Unable to deploy EJBs in JBoss

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb-3.0

I have followed this tutorial:
[EJB invocations from a remote client using JNDI](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/EJB+invocations+from+a+remote+client+using+JNDI)

First, I have packaged everything in a war, and I could deploy successfully the war in my JBoss AS 7.

However, when I tried to move the EJBs and their interfaces into a JAR file and I added the JAR as a maven dependency in the WAR, I started to get this exception:

```
19:19:13,780 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-4) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."remote-ejb3-war.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."remote-ejb3-war.war".POST_MODULE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "remote-ejb3-war.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:127) [jboss-as-server-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA.jar:1.0.4.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA.jar:1.0.4.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.as.quickstarts.ejb.remote.stateless.impl.CalculatorBean from [Module "deployment.remote-ejb3-war.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.BusinessViewAnnotationProcessor.getEjbClass(BusinessViewAnnotationProcessor.java:217)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.BusinessViewAnnotationProcessor.deploy(BusinessViewAnnotationProcessor.java:87)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:120) [jboss-as-server-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.as.quickstarts.ejb.remote.stateless.impl.CalculatorBean from [Module "deployment.remote-ejb3-war.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.CR1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.CR1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.CR1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.CR1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.CR1]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.BusinessViewAnnotationProcessor.getEjbClass(BusinessViewAnnotationProcessor.java:215)
    ... 7 more

19:19:13,882 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server] (MSC service thread 1-6) HQ221024: Started Netty Acceptor version 3.6.2.Final-c0d783c 127.0.0.1:5455 for CORE protocol
```

By the way, I have created beans.xml file under:

- JarProject\src\main\resources\META-INF
- WarProject\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF

I must absolutely keep the WAR as a wrapper only. I don't want it to contain business of the EJBs.

Here it is my pom.xml file of the WAR project:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>learningejb3</groupId>
    <artifactId>remote-ejb3-war</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>


    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <version.compiler.plugin>3.2</version.compiler.plugin>
    </properties>


    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>learningejb3</groupId>
            <artifactId>remote-ejb3</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${version.compiler.plugin}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
                    <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I don't get any compilation error of the WAR and when expending the maven dependencies of the WAR I find "remote-ejb3" which is the JAR:

[image]

Thank you a lot.

Comment: Have you verified your .war file before deploy it checking that your .jar dependency is in your WEB-INF/lib folder ? your pom file is relevant here too, you can write it in your question to get more information about your problem

Comment: @yersan Yes, I verified under the generated WAR and I could find the jar under WEB-INF/lib

Comment: I understand that you are deploying your war file using your eclipse IDE, In this case I would try to isolate your problem deploying it manually. Instead of use your IDE, start your JBoss using the command line and deploy your war file using the JBoss console. It's an idea, I don't see problems deploying your EJBs together with your war, if you have verified that org.jboss.as.quickstarts.ejb.remote.stateless.impl.CalculatorBean class is inside of a .jar file in /WEB-INF/lib folder, that class is in the class loading for your war file.

Comment: Oh :( I feel disappointed about Eclipse. Indeed, when I copy the generated war manually into "Deployments" folder of JBoss but I start JBoss using Eclipse, the application get deployed without any problem, and I even see the JNDI of my EJBs in the log... Maybe I have a compliant problem in my Eclipse IDE?

Comment: One thing more, when I closed the jar project in Eclipse, I could deploy in eclipse! I don't understand... It seems there must be a setting in Eclipse.

Comment: From the stack trace posted, it seems that you're only packing your interfaces in the JAR. Is it possible for you to update your question with the structure of your project?